# Decipher SQL Server page storage

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
  (
     col1 VARCHAR(1)
  )

INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES     (NULL)

DBCC traceon(3604)

DBCC ind(0, tbl, -1)

DBCC page(0, 1, 290, 3) WITH tableresults /*Change page number as required*/
```

Output

```
PAGE HEADER:    Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 9 Record Type PRIMARY_RECORD
PAGE HEADER:    Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 9 Record Attributes    NULL_BITMAP
PAGE HEADER:    Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 9 Record Size 9
Slot 0 Offset 0x60 Length 9 Memory Dump @0x000000001646A060     
10000400 01000100 d8                          ........Ø
```

What is **d8** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just padding,

[image]

The row only needs to take up the 7 bytes highlighted above (a null or empty varchar column at the end of the row [needs no space](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/column-order-doesnt-matter-generally-but-it-depends/)) but [the minimum row size is 9 bytes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14854/3690) so you are seeing garbage from whatever was on the page before in the last two bytes.

Comment: I hope it mean something. It is taking 1 byte. d8(hexa) to binary is 11011000 and 216 in decimal. Could it be because of varchar takes 2 bytes irrespective of what data is stored?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta - Now you've posted the create table it is possible to be more precise. And no it doesn't mean anything in this case.

Comment: thanks for explaining. Did you use any tool to read page internals as posted in screenshot?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta SQL Server Internals Viewer on CodePlex. Only works with older versions of SSMS